# Codeigniter Accessing methods via command line

Tags: php, linux, codeigniter

I'm trying to access a controller method setup to do a simple database insert, however I cannot access it. I can access it from the web just fine, and I don't need to be logged in to run it.

***However*** If I navigate to my project directory, and from my command line type:

```
php index.php My_Controller/My_Method
```

and instead it runs **welcome controller** `function __construct()` and spews of a bunch of Undefined index errors. In fact I could type `php index.php jibberish/doesnotexist`  and it will still give me

```
<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Undefined index: HTTP_HOST</p>
<p>Filename: controllers/welcome.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 45</p>
```

Why is it running the welcome controller instead of a controller I specify it to run? I also modified my **.htaccess** file to remove index.php

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

and if I try to do it without the index.php from my base directory I get "could not open input file".

Comment: use spaces instead of /, for your example: index.php controller method arg1 arg2

Answer (score 0):

Solved: Make sure that your uri_protocol is set to auto:

```
 $config['uri_protocol']    = 'AUTO';
```